# Constraint in Python @property setter not applied

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have pretty simple class, which converts temperature to Fahrenheit, in additional it makes sure that value are larger than -273

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print('Getting_value')
        return self._temperature


    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value
```

if I run following code

```
c = Celsius()
c.temperature=23
c.to_fahrenheit()
```

I get expected Output:

```
Setting value
Getting_value
Out[89]:
73.4
```

now trying to set up temperature to -275, we get error as expected!

```
c = Celsius()
c.temperature=-275
c.to_fahrenheit()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 c = Celsius()
>   ----> 2 c.temperature=-275
>         3 c.to_fahrenheit()
>
> in temperature(self, value)
>        15     def temperature(self, value):
>        16         if value < -273:
>   ---> 17             raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
>        18         print("Setting value")
>        19         self._temperature = value
>
> ValueError: Temperature below -273 is not possible

so far so good! But problem is if I try to set up temperature during initiation of the class I can choose -275 and it will not prompt error

```
c = Celsius(-275)
c.to_fahrenheit()

> Getting_value Out[88]:
> -463.0
```

My question is why its not triggering error ? As I understood  `@temperature.setter` will make sure to check if temperature is <-273 but for some reason it passes it.

Comment: `self._temperature = temperature` you aren't using the property, you are using the private variable that the property uses. Use the property: `self.temperature = temperature`

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a duplicate, but I cannot find the target...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's happened because you use in **init** method

`self._temperature = temperature`

And your temperature setter don't execute. You can change your code to

`self.temperature = temperature`

It will execute temperature setter method and raise Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not call the property, instead you've called the private attribute. You should change constructor of your class to it:

```
def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
    self.temperature = temperature
```

Now when you initiate your class, the property will use and in bad input you will get the exception.